# How do I insert an Image in this TablePrintable Java Class

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I am a Java leaner. I have a JTable which captures user input. I would want to print this table with a logo image at the top. I found the [TablePrintable.java](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~erland/gemensamt/src/javax/swing/TablePrintable.java) to be a good implementation.

Now the problem is I do not know where to put/draw within the `TablePrintable` the image which will be the header without distorting the code. Please assist, I could have posted what I have tried but in this case I am stuck and I do not know where to start.

Comment: You're a leaner, you want to print an image with a `JTable`, so, you've pretty much jumped straight to the three most advance topics available, `JTable`, printing and graphics. Hope you enjoy swimming in the deep end with the sharks. Okay, you could take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660448/table-print-does-not-fit-to-page-size/26665276#26665276) which modifies the `TablePrintable` to support scaling, I know, not what you asked for, but it will give you a start with how complex a task it will be to implement your idea...

Comment: You'll also want to have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer well, thanks to an invitation to these advanced topics. I am trying to follow the example you have given me. I have followed [this example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678235/java-change-margins-when-printing-jtable). No problem with that. The problem is instead of Strings as My Header, I want to put an image there as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AJGi9.png).

Comment: @trashgod These questions are different! I encourage you to pay attention to them and CHECK HOW I want them Implemented!