# How to print transparent header JTable to PDF file

Tags: java, netbeans, printing, header, jtable

I stuck in print JTable to PDF file because of this:

[I have transparent the header of JTable but when I print to PDF it become like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTJxV.png)
[This my JTable transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxzx2.png)

This is my JTable code: `JTable.setShowGrid(true);
JTable.setOpaque(false);
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)JTable.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);`

```
JTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        JTable.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

My print code:

```
 public static class Printer implements Printable {
final Component comp;

public Printer(Component comp){
    this.comp = comp;
}

@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index) 
        throws PrinterException {
    if (page_index > 0) {
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    // get the bounds of the component
    Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
    double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
    double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

    // get the bounds of the printable area
    double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
    double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();

    double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
    double pYStart = format.getImageableY();

    double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
    double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;


    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
    g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
    comp.paint(g2);

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

}

Please help me. Tks all!

Comment: How, exactly, are you printing the table?  How have you setup the table when it's displayed on the screen?

Comment: Well, `JTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));` is an issue, and I'm surprised you've not had other issues, Swing doesn't support alpha based colors in this way, it only supports components which are fully transparent or fully opaque, you can fake transparency, but not like this.  Consider using `setOpaque(false)` instead

Comment: You mustn't realise that `JTable` has it's own [printing API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing) which is lot easier to use then what you're doing ... also when printing, you should use `print` or `printAll` not `paint`

Comment: I put JTable in a panel and I print all the components in that Panel, not just the JTable. Can you help me fix my transparent header code ?

Comment: How do you deal with multiple pages?

Comment: I don't know. I just want to print that panel.

Comment: Okay, so this is actually a really complex problem, if you want to do it properly. `JTable`'s print API supports multiple page printing, so you need away you can print behind it, possibly based on the page offset x the page height so the image doesn't repeat (unless you want it to).  The problem is, the printable used by the `JTable` is not particularly customisable (you can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660448/table-print-does-not-fit-to-page-size/26665276#26665276) for en example)

Comment: This doesn't even take into account making sure that the header, table, cells are transparent, around about now I'd be suggesting Jasper Reports [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067)