# Printing 2 JTables on the same page in Java

Tags: java, jtable

I have 2 JTables and I would like to print them on the same page. The height of my Java knowledge right now only affords me the ability to print them on 2 separate pages. Below is an excerpt of what I'm working on. I would like to print the userTable and the compTable on the same page. Thanks for your help

```
public void printTable(int type)
    {
        if(type == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            userTable.getTableHeader().setFont(mainFont);
            userTable.setFont(mainFont);


            compTable.getTableHeader().setFont(mainFont);
            compTable.setFont(mainFont);

            MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Certificate Values");
            MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page{0,number,integer}");

            MessageFormat header1 = new MessageFormat("Interpolated Values");
            MessageFormat footer1 = new MessageFormat("Page{0,number,integer}");

            try
            {   
                userTable.print( JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
                compTable.print( JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header1, footer1);
            }
            catch (PrinterException ex)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more detail. What did you try?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: So, printing is not a simple task/subject, `JTable` is among one of the more complex components available, you're combining to difficult tasks together.  There a number of possible issues you need to overcome, like, what happens when there's not enough room horizontally or vertically to fit the tables on a single page?

Comment: If you're interested in knowing how complex this becomes, you could look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660448/table-print-does-not-fit-to-page-size/26665276#26665276)

Comment: A "simple" solution might be to combine the two `TableModel`s into a single `TableModel` and apply that to a `JTable` (offscreen), which can then be printed, as an idea

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to print two tables on the same page?

Comment: @prasad_ my report looks better that way

Comment: How large are the tables? How many rows and columns in each table?

Comment: @prasad_ the userTable has 4 rows and the compTable has 10 rows. They each have 2 columns.

Comment: @codeX You can use Apache POI to format the two tables' data within a page of an Excel spreadsheet (and print it).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tried and the code is below. The program extracts both the table data, formats as HTML tables and results in HTML content. The resulting HTML is displayed in a `JEditorPane` as editor content. The `JEditorPane`'s `print()` method lets print the content within a page as two tables.

**NOTES:**

1. This is okay if the table sizes (rows) won't change. Also, note the HTML generated is very basic and there are more refined solutions (can be found thru Google search).
2. The `JEditorPane` supports only HTML 3.2. This means limited CSS and
   styling capabilities. In case one is looking for more styling one can show the generated HTML content in a JavaFX's `WebView` and print.
3. Another option is show the generated HTML in a web browser and print.
4. Apache POI is already suggested.

**HtmlTablePrinter.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class HtmlTablePrinter {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new HtmlTablePrinter().displayTable();
    }

    private void displayTable() {
        final JTable table1 = getTable1();
        final JTable table2 = getTable2();
        JButton previewButton = new JButton("Print preview");
        previewButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            try {
                printPreview(getHtml(table1, table2));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table1));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table2));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tables Print Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(previewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setLocation(200, 100);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTable getTable1() {
        String data [][] = {{"Violet", "Indigo"},
                {"Blue", "Green"},
                {"Yellow", "Orange"},
                {"Red", "Others"}};
        String header [] = {"Colors 1", "Colors 2"};
        return new JTable(data, header);
    }

    private JTable getTable2() {
        TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
            @Override public int getColumnCount() {
                return 2;
            }
            @Override public int getRowCount() {
                return 10;
            }
            @Override public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return ("Cell at row " + (row+1) + " col " + (col+1));
            }
        };
        return new JTable(model);
    }

    private String getHtml(JTable table1, JTable table2) {
        String style = "<style>table, th, td {border:1px solid #C0C0C0;" +
                "font-family:sans-serif;padding:2px;}</style>";
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        line.append("<html>")
            .append("<head>").append(style).append("</head>")
            .append("<body>");
        line = getTableHtml(table1, line);
        line = getTableHtml(table2, line);
        line.append("</body>").append("</html>");
        return line.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder getTableHtml(JTable table, StringBuilder line) {
        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        line.append("<table>");
        line.append("<tr>");
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            line.append("<th scope='col'>");
            line.append(model.getColumnName(j));
            line.append("</th>");
        }
        line.append("</tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            line.append("<tr>");
            for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                line.append("<td>");
                line.append(model.getValueAt(i, j));
                line.append("</td>");
            }
            line.append("</tr>");
        }
        line.append("</table>").append("<br/>");
        return line;
    }

    public void printPreview(String html) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Tables Print Preview");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", html);
        editorPane.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print...");
        printButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            MessageFormat hd = new MessageFormat("Colors & stuff");
            MessageFormat ft = new MessageFormat("Page {0,number,integer}");
            try {
                editorPane.print(hd, ft);
            } catch(Exception ex) { 
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(editorPane));
        panel.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        panel.add(printButton);
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.setSize(500, 700);
        dialog.setLocation(300, 50);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```